# react-native init error with nodejs

Tags: node.js, react-native

I got this error when I use command react-native init hello in nodejs

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:855:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:455:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:369:17)
```

Comment: I got it https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2681

Comment: you can post your comment as an answer and accept your own answer since you have resolved it.